# Which layer should I implement Entity-DTO conversion?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, entity, dto

I used TypeORM to create an entity called `User` and `School`:

```js
@Entity()
export class User {
  // ...

  @ManyToOne(() => School, school => school.id)
  school: School;

  // ...

  static from(
    uid: string,
    name: string,
    email: string,
    studentId: string,
    password: string,
    tel: string,
    role: string,
    school: School,
    changePasswordToken?: string
  ): User {
    const user = new User();
    user.uid = uid;
    user.name = name;
    user.email = email;
    user.studentId = studentId;
    user.password = password;
    user.tel = tel;
    user.role = role;
    user.school = school;
    user.changePasswordToken = changePasswordToken;
    return user;
  }
}
```

```js
@Entity()
export class School {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  @OneToMany(() => Product, product => product.school)
  @OneToMany(() => Order, order => order.school)
  @OneToMany(() => User, user => user.school)
  id: string;

  // ...

  static from(
    id: string,
    name: string,
    legalName: string,
    address: string,
    tel: string,
    ceo: string,
    brn: string,
    mobrn: string,
    password: string
  ): School {
    const school = new School();
    school.id = id;
    school.name = name;
    school.legalName = legalName;
    school.address = address;
    school.tel = tel;
    school.ceo = ceo;
    school.brn = brn;
    school.mobrn = mobrn;
    school.password = password;
    return school;
  }
}
```

`User` depends on the id of the `School` through foreign key called `schoolId`.
Among Stack Overflow's answers similar to this topic, I found that implementing Entity-DTO conversion is recommended in the Service layer.

So I wrote the following code for `SchoolsService`:

```js
@Injectable()
export class SchoolsService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(School) private readonly schoolRepository: Repository<School>
  ) { }
  async findOne(id: string): Promise<ResponseSchoolDto> {
    const school = await this.schoolRepository.findOne({ where: { id } });
    const responseSchoolDto = plainToInstance(ResponseSchoolDto, school);
    return responseSchoolDto
  }
}
```

Code for `UsersService`:

```js
@Injectable
export class UsersService {
  constructor(private readonly schoolsService: SchoolsService) { }
  create(userData: CreateUserDto): Promise<User> {
    const user = instanceToPlain(userData);
    // WHAT SHOULD I DO?
    // const responseSchoolDto = this.schoolsService.findOne(userData.schoolId);
    // const school = plainToInstance(School, responseSchoolDto);
    return this.userRepository.save(user);
  }
}
```

As mentioned above, DTO must be converted to Entity to provide a `schoolId` to User Entity because Service is designed to return DTO.
However, I think the code I wrote is inappropriate because `UsersService` depends on `SchoolsService`, `School`(Entity), and DTO. No matter how much I think about it, the only way to solve this problem is for Service to return Entity.

While I was looking for a solution to this problem, I found that someone implemented the method of converting DTO to Entity inside of DTO. However, I don't think this method is appropriate either because I think DTO should have only pure data. Is there an efficient structure to solve this problem?

Comment: invoke the mapper at controller layer as DTOs are models for the client-server boundary. You can levarage on nestjs interceptors like this: https://automapperts.netlify.app/docs/nestjs#mapinterceptor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be late to the party,
But I'm posting anyway, you can convert the ResponseSchoolDto school with plaintToInstance and set the user's school value with recovery. Then you save your user.
But you should not inject one service into another. Use a repository directly to retrieve a school and then set it on the user.

Another way is to create Mappers.
You have several solutions to do this:

- [@automapper/nestjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@automapper/nestjs)
- [typevert](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typevert)
- implement your own Injectable Mapper with a custom function
- Create a builder
- ...

Advantages of delegating the instruction to a separate Mapper:

- centralized mapping, therefore more robust to changes
- more readable so a lower cost of understanding

### Tips

- pay attention to names:

```js
userData: UserData; // OK
userEntity: UserEntity // OK
user: User // OK
userData: CreateUserDto // NON OK
etc...
```

- respect the good layered REST architecture. One layer depends on another but does not depend on itself.
- Do not hesitate to create intermediate classes (mapper, builder, manager, helpers, validators, etc.) to delegate actions. This way, functions are shorter, better named, easier to test and maintain.

More discussions on the subject:
[NestJS, how and where to build response DTOs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72038893/nestjs-how-and-where-to-build-response-dtos)

Comment: Upvoted, But yikes thats some serious over complication for mapping data. I think you get 99% with mapping functions that convert the entity to your DTO for use. Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: You're right, the mapping functions do the job very well. It's a simple design choice. If you want to keep a clean class, using a mapper is a good way to go. Personally, I prefer to delimit the different parts of the code as much as possible, even if it means having more classes.